# Is there a way to trigger formatting in excel documents via Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am working on an automatic excel sheet comparison python script, but I am having trouble making my changes show up when I open the excel document. Basically, it does a cell level comparison and adds a red fill if the cell changed and a green fill if the cell did not change. I am using openpyxl to edit the value, and change the fill color. After the code runs, I open the excel file to see no changes. However, when I click on the cells themselves, I can then see the color fill change. I need help finding a solution that will automatically trigger that formatting to appear before I open the excel file. Does anyone have experience with this?

To run, create an excel file named 'test', then add values to rows in first column of Sheet1. Create a second Sheet2 and add the same values for half of first column, then change values for second half of first column. Save, close file, run. Then look for changes.

```
import pandas as pd 
import openpyxl as op
from openpyxl.utils.cell import get_column_letter
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

def main():
    old_tab = "Sheet1"
    new_tab = "Sheet2"

    # set up A1:A10 on Sheet1 all to be = 10
    # ... then on Sheet2, have A1:A5 be = 10, and A6:A10 be = 20
    path = './test.xlsx'

    # set up list to track indices that should be highlighted red
    cells_to_highlight_red = []
    red_fill = PatternFill(fill_type=None, start_color='FFFFFFFF', end_color='FF0000')

    # set up list to track indices that should be highlighted green
    cells_to_highlight_green = []
    green_fill = PatternFill(fill_type=None, start_color='FFFFFFFF', end_color='008000')

    old_sheet = pd.read_excel(path,  sheet_name=old_tab, data_only=True, header=None).fillna('-')
    new_sheet = pd.read_excel(path,  sheet_name=new_tab, data_only=True, header=None).fillna('-')

    # do cell by cell comparison to see if cells have changed
    bool_df = old_sheet.eq(new_sheet)

    # go through each column
    for col_index in range(bool_df.shape[1]):
        # then through each row of the bool_df. 
        # ... if the cell is False, that means a change has occurred
        # ... if the cell is not False, so True, that means no 
        for row_index, row in enumerate(bool_df.iloc[:,col_index].values.flatten()):
            if row == False:
                col_letter = get_column_letter(col_index+1)
                trg_cell = col_letter + str(row_index+1)
                trg_cell.replace(" ", "")
                # if this is true, then there was no value to begin or end, so do not add to list to track
                if old_sheet.iloc[row_index, col_index] == "-" and new_sheet.iloc[row_index, col_index] == "-":
                    continue
                cells_to_highlight_red.append(trg_cell)
            else:
                col_letter = get_column_letter(col_index+1)
                trg_cell = col_letter + str(row_index+1)
                trg_cell.replace(" ", "")
                # if this is true, then there was no value to begin or end, so do not add to list to track
                if old_sheet.iloc[row_index, col_index] == "-" and new_sheet.iloc[row_index, col_index] == "-":
                    continue
                cells_to_highlight_green.append(trg_cell)

    target_workbook = op.load_workbook( filename=path )
    target_sheet = target_workbook["Sheet2"]

    for trg_col_row in cells_to_highlight_red:
        cell_to_edit = target_sheet[trg_col_row]
        cell_to_edit.fill = red_fill

    for trg_col_row in cells_to_highlight_green:
        cell_to_edit = target_sheet[trg_col_row]
        cell_to_edit.fill = green_fill

    target_workbook.save( path )


main()
```

Comment: Could you try reducing your code down to small example of what's going wrong? For example, just take out everything that isn't adding color to the excel file so that someone can help you more easily. Right now, no one on SO is going to be able to run that code and reproduce your results.If you cut down your code, you're far more likely to get a response.